# information about different databases

Tags: database, database-design

I want to understand different types of databases out there i.e. mysql, mongo, cassandra. I want to be an expert in databases thus starting by understanding the reason for existence of so many databases(I know each servers different needs)

Can anyone point me to a nice article/video explaining what i need?

Comment: Being an expert in databases arbitrarily might mean knowing the ins and outs of each. In learning this you will grow an understanding of their differences and applications. This site is for debugging, not necessarily for questions like this

Comment: Think how you would use them. You'll quickly find stuff that is easy for one DB and hard with another. The differences are in how well different use cases are supported.

Comment: There could be as many answers to this question as there are databases to provide information about. It really doesn't fit into a Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this useful : http://db-engines.com/en/system/Cassandra%3BMongoDB%3BMySQL%3BPostgreSQL%3BSQLite

Here is another nice article : http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

Answer (score 0):

The major difference is between SQL/ relational databases (traditional) such as Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, FireBird, MySQL, SQLite.

And NoSQL databases such as MongoDB, Cassandra. These mostly retain the database property of "durability" against power loss/ sudden shutdown, but are designed for higher speed & volume of data with fewer transactional guarantees of "isolation" or "consistency". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

See:

- http://slashdot.org/topic/bi/sql-vs-nosql-which-is-better/
- http://readwrite.com/2013/03/25/when-nosql-databases-are-good-for-you#awesm=~oiGNB6GtNKoHNF
- http://www.mongodb.com/nosql

Some of the links in the other answers are interesting, too!

Answer (score 0):

- http://nosql-database.org/

  Your Ultimate Guide to the
  Non-Relational Universe!
- http://martinfowler.com/nosql.html

  NoSQL Distilled is a book co-written by popular software architecture guru Martin Fowler.
- http://pragprog.com/book/rwdata/seven-databases-in-seven-weeks

  A book written as a practical hands-on guide to learn the basics of Redis, Neo4J, CouchDB, MongoDB, HBase, Riak, and Postgres.